# Broken encryption when entering characters

Tags: java, aes

during the encryption process I already noticed the error when putting characters like these here in a string  ღ♉✘⊗♤⚅♥☻�¤, the data is encrypted, but when trying to decrypt the data, it is not possible .

with this error when trying to create a json in the fields where it has the characters, or is missing " or ,

```
private static final String KEY = "34753668217A25432A462W4A614E6451";

    private static final byte[] NULL_BYTES_16 = new byte[] { 0x00,
            0x00,
            0x00,
            0x00,
            0x00,
            0x00,
            0x00,
            0x00,
            0x00,
            0x00,
            0x00,
            0x00,
            0x00,
            0x00,
            0x00,
            0x00 };



    public static String encrypt(final String data) {
        final byte[] keyBytes = Hex.decode(KEY);
        String dataCrypto = "";
        final SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");

        byte[] d = data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        final int blockSize = 16;
        d = padding(data.getBytes(), blockSize);
        dataCrypto = new String(Hex.encode(encrypt(key, d, NULL_BYTES_16, "AES/CBC/NoPadding")));
        return dataCrypto;
    }


    
    public static String decrypt(final String data) {
        final byte[] keyBytes = Hex.decode(KEY);
        String dataDecrypto = "";
        final SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        final byte[] d = Hex.decode(data);
        dataDecrypto = new String(decrypt(key, d, NULL_BYTES_16, "AES/CBC/NoPadding"));
        return dataDecrypto;
    }

    private static byte[]
            encrypt(final Key key, final byte[] text, final byte[] iv, final String encryptionAlgorithmValue) {
        try {
            final Provider provider = Security.getProvider("SunJCE");
            final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(encryptionAlgorithmValue, provider);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
            final byte[] res = cipher.doFinal(text);
            return res;
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("MAC computation failed.", e);
        }
    }

    private static byte[]
            decrypt(final Key key, final byte[] text, final byte[] iv, final String encryptionAlgorithmValue) {
        try {
            final Provider provider = Security.getProvider("SunJCE");
            final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(encryptionAlgorithmValue, provider);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
            final byte[] res = cipher.doFinal(text);
            return res;
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("MAC computation failed.", e);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("all")
    private static byte[] padding(byte[] data, final Integer blockSize) {
        // Blocksize de 16 para AES e de 8 para TDES
        data = concat(data, new byte[] { (byte) 0x80 });
        if (data.length % blockSize == 0) {
            return data;
        }
        final byte[] paddedData = Arrays.copyOf(data, data.length + blockSize - data.length % blockSize);
        return paddedData;
    }
```

data to be encrypted

```
{
    "requestId": "waldir_104-010102993851",
    "issuerId": "22",
    "tokenRequestorId": "12300000001",
    "schemeId": "Elo",
    "panHash": "AEF2397762DC8226FD4786E05A1392D47FA621345C3E4BE674B61400C23F5609",
    "cardEncryptionInfo": {
        "cardSensitiveData": "3772D0FCCD1CE987872F7B7D41F2F3CF1C4C9F0A9F1A6F5C2C6C6B7B05DDEBDA13CAE351234C4DD69C317D278219D1403D1B350673D73E62D9D5418167BC7AF1157B928AC1780FCE406AA2D9C815E35B2A844F0D9EAD82C9EEECC9C315C688CD675A7D1D6CFF7FA51EBB63A7C86DDB137C7F66FEDA55AF969158D90023FFB0BF",
        "cardSensitiveDataFormat": "CardData",
        "encryptionReference": "BRADESCO.TRANS.02",
        "encryptionIV": "6071656686361687"    },
    "accountRiskData": {
        "clientType": "76",
        "accountScore": 1,
        "accountScoringAlgorithm": "10",
        "accountScoringAlgoVersion": "10",
        "accountCreationPeriod": 0,
        "cpf": "1234567890111",
        "userEmail": "user@domain.com.br",
        "address": "TESTEChacára Praça Estação Área Colônia, 1200 - Núcleo ''''''  ღ♉✘⊗♤⚅♥☻�¤",
        "zip": "06455-914",
        "accountId": "fc440120-6f0b-11ea-bdb8-398790b53374",
        "simSwapTimePeriodIndication": "A"    },
    "deviceRiskData": {
        "phoneNumberScore": "5",
        "phoneNumber": "+55119876543210",
        "fullDeviceNumber": "119123412342",
        "color": "green2",
        "deviceScore": 1,
        "deviceScoringAlgorithm": "10",
        "deviceScoringAlgoVersion": "10",
        "deviceCountry": "BR",
        "deviceID": "1234567891",
        "ipv4": "10.82.2.222",
        "manufacturer": "Apple",
        "brand": "Apple",
        "model": "A1549",
        "name":"Paiva du corte ߒ蜢,",
        "networkOperator": "testeMaia",
        "networkType": "GSM",
        "osType": "Android",
        "osVersion": "10",
        "timeZoneManager": "CARRIER",
        "deviceType": "SMARTPHONE"    },
    "walletRiskData": {
        "recommendation": "aprovar2",
        "walletId": "1fc3f7a0-3176-11ea-b2e4-15074b0e5031",
        "cardTenurePeriod": 0,
        "walletCreationPeriod": 0,
        "walletCardholderNameMatches": true,
        "tokensOnDevice": 1,
        "cardInputMethod": "teste",
        "flowIndication": "GREEN",
        "flowAlgorithm": "10",
        "flowAlgorithmVersion": "10"    }
}
```

Comment: Always, always, always specify a Charset when constructing a String from bytes or when calling a String’s `getBytes()` method.  Your encrypt and decrypt methods both call `new String` without specifying a Charset.  Your encrypt method has `data.getBytes()` (which is strange, considering just two lines earlier, you correctly passed a Charset to getBytes).

Comment: On Windows the standard character set is actually Windows1252, which only allows for single byte encoding. Note that your key is not fully hex, not sure what you are doing there. Don't know why you'd use bit padding and especially why you would implement it the way you're doing now, with horrid buffer handling. Don't know why "MAC" exception handling is in there, while there is no MAC. Don't know why you are explicitly using a provider. The whole question to me is one big **why???**.

Comment: FYI: Your padding ([ISO 7816-4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#ISO/IEC_7816-4)) is supported by BouncyCastle: `AES/CBC/ISO7816-4Padding`. Note that a static IV (unless only for testing purposes) is a vulnerability.